# Is there a way to compare md5 on unix with md5 on hadoop with python?

Tags: python, hadoop, md5

I need to compare md5s between a unix server and a hadoop server. I would like to do this with python. I would like to use pythons hashlib but I don't know if I can do this with hadoop or if I will have to use some sort of stdin/stdout.

Comment: Both Hadoop and Python support MD5. See http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html and  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MD5Hash.html . What do you have available to integrated the two?

Comment: I want to use python to compare the md5s. I need to compare the md5 that is on the hadoop cluster to the md5 on the unix box.

Comment: And what are these MD5s about? A file, a string, ...?

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-hdfs-user/201103.mbox/%3CAANLkTinR8zM2QUb+T-drAC6PDmwJm8qcdxL48hzxBNoi@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by doing with "hadoop". I believe, you could be running a particular program using hadoop. In that you can use the md5 calculation routine.

```
import hashlib
hash = hashlib.md5()
hash.update( "stringformd5" )
hash.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download it to you'r local file system
with

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal
```

Python example:

```
import hashlib
import subprocess

def md5_for_file(f, block_size=2**20):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    while True:
        data = f.read(block_size)
        if not data:
            break
        md5.update(data)
    return md5.digest()

bashCommand = "hadoop fs -copyToLocal" + from + " " + to
hash = hashlib.md5()
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print md_for_file(to)
```